# How do you say "ludic cosmology" in latin?

Tags: english-to-latin-translation

is it cosmologia ludica?
is that the correct spelling?

i'm getting a lot of discrepancy here from scholars.
so there are two words that require translation.
cosmos
and ludic.

i'm assuming both have latin roots.
and then grammatically how would they be combined to form "ludic cosmology" in latin?

thank you!
-Aaron

Comment: Welcome to the site, Aaron! Can you edit your question (not just leave a comment but actually edit the question) to explain what you want to mean by "ludic cosmology"? To get a good translation it's not enough to have the words but the intent behind them, and this is an issue with translating short phrases.

Comment: I closed the question but it will certainly be reopened if you can elaborate on what you are after. This is a promising question but in need of a bit of polishing.

Comment: Thanks! I reopened the question. It would help if you could explain what "ludic cosmology" means to you; this is the first time I've heard the word "ludic", so I can offer no translation. But perhaps someone else can.

Comment: Aaron, can you explain what exactly is ludic cosmology and where you found that term? We can't translate something if we don't know what it means!